# Dynamic Programming Question - What is the base case?

Tags: dynamic-programming

Been preparing of Coding Interviews. I have been trying to beef up my dynamic programming skills and came across Alvin's awesome channel and this great video about some of the approaches to take.
In one of the programming sections - The problem statement is "Can you construct the target string with the contents in an array" - he goes on to correctly use recursion as an approach. But I got stuck in his base [case](https://youtu.be/oBt53YbR9Kk?t=8095).

He indicates for example that this should return true:

```
canConstruct('StakeBoard', ['sta', 'te', 'bo', 'ard']
```

He goes on to settle the recursion base case as the following returning true by literally saying "Because to generate and empty string, you can generally take no-zero elements from the array!". **This is the part I did not understand. What does non-zero elements of the array mean here to make this a base case?**

```
canConstruct('', ['cat', dog'])
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the problem statement instead of resorting to a link to a video. If the link is broken in future, this question can remain intact.

Comment: Did you mean `ska` instead of `sta`? In the case of the empty string, your recursive base-case may start initially with `""` as the starting point, which would mean the empty string is always supported regardless of arguments. If not, then `""` would only accept an array with `""` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Because to generate an empty string, you can generally take no-zero elements from the array!"

It should be something like

`"Because to generate an empty string, you can generally take no or zero elements from the array!"`

The next question states that

> What does non-zero elements of the array mean here to make this a base case?

Actually, he meant

`In case the target is empty, no matter what array of words are given, taking no or zero words will return the answer true.`

We call a case `base case` when we have a definite answer for that case. And the case described above definitely looks like one thereby addressed as the `base case`.

Comment: Im unable to visualize this - how do we arrive at this conclusion? I mean if we take an example  construct "abcdef" using ["ab", "cd", "ef"] ->  how does contains("", [any array]) be true?

Comment: The problem states, "Can the target string be built from the contents of an array". To construct "abcdef" using ["ab", "cd", "ef"], first "ab" is taken from the target, leaving "cdef". Then "cd" is removed, leaving "ef". Finally, "ef" is taken, and we reach the base case ("", [any array]), which is considered a success. As there is nothing left to construct, thereby this infers `contains("", [any array])` to be true.

Comment: oh damn..i see where you are going with this. thanks. i thinkt this last one clarified it